# Data Jpa Test fails to load properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am using Hashi Corp vault in Spring Boot project. I am able to run the project without any issue. But when I run unit tests, `secret-id` and `role-id` are not being passed. I tried the following but got an exception saying both are empty. Tried hard coding the values, that didn't work either

**EmployeeTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles(value = "ide")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class EmployeeTest
{
    private final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    public void getEmployeeById()
    {
        Employee employee=employeeRepository.getOne(13L);
        logger.info(employee.toString());
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I am able to pass `secret-id` and `role-id` through VM arguments but still properties are not resolving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out when using profile from `src/main/resources/application-ide.yml` in spring boot test, properties are not being replaced by vault vaules. Copying the same file to  `src/test/resources/application-ide.yml` fixes the issue.

**TL;DR**
For Spring Boot testing always better to use properties file from `src/test/resources` rather than `src/main/resources`